# VHDL: How does one assign custom values to identifiers of an enumerated type?

Tags: vhdl, 7segmentdisplay

For a design with seven segment displays, it will be easier in modelsim simulation if one can see the actual display value going into the seven segment display e.g hexadecimal D which is "1000010" in binary could appear as an enumerated type 'ss_D' in the simulation waveform. How does one create an enum with custom assigned values for this purpose?

I know it does not hurt to just concentrate on the value going into the decoder for the seven segment display instead and see it as hexadecimal in the wave window. But the question here is, generally how to assign custom value to VHDL enum type?

Comment: Is your goal to visualize the LED signals in ModelSim or to represent them symbolically as enumerated type in VHDL? If it's only the former then you could define a custom radix in ModelSim, like so:
radix define led-state {
B"1000010" "ss_D"
}

Comment: @TonyK This works fine, but is not fully supported in ModelSim light versions like ModelSim Altera Edition.

Answer (score 6):

See Ashenden "Designer's Guide to VHDL" (chapter 20.2).

given the type definition from the other answer

```
type ss_enum is (ss_0, ss_1, ss_2, ss_3, ss_4, ss_5, ss_6, ss_7, ss_8,
                     ss_9, ss_A, ss_B, ss_C, ss_D, ss_E, ss_F);
```

we can assign a representation to it via an attribute:

```
attribute encoding of ss_d[return ss_enum] : literal is b"1000010";
```

and then we should be able to access that value via the attribute syntax:

```
signal ss : ss_enum;
signal LED_port : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
...
LED_port <= ss`encoding;
```

I do not know how Modelsim will display the `LED_port` signal, but I would expect it to display the `ss_enum` signal using its enumeration values `ss_D` etc.

In practice I find it unnecessary to assign encodings, I would declare a constant array for this purpose, the syntax is shorter and tidier, and it'll usually synthesise down to the same thing.

```
constant lookup : array(ss_enum) of std_logic_vector(6 downto 0) := (
   ss_0 => ...
   ...
   ss_D => b"1000010",
   ... );
...
LED_Port <= lookup(ss);
```

This approach doesn't answer your waveform display question, but I find it's better to make the simulation self-checking; then, looking at waveforms is the exception (when something went wrong) rather than the rule, and therefore it's much less important.

Answer (score 3):

Enumerated types are easy to declare:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity enum is
end entity;

architecture foo of enum is
    type ss_enum is (ss_0, ss_1, ss_2, ss_3, ss_4, ss_5, ss_6, ss_7, ss_8,
                     ss_9, ss_A, ss_B, ss_C, ss_D, ss_E, ss_F);
    signal sseg: ss_enum;
    signal hex_in:   unsigned (3 downto 0) := "0000";
begin
COUNT:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        if hex_in < "1111" then
            hex_in <= hex_in + 1;
        else
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

LOOKUP_ENUM:

    sseg <= ss_enum'VAL(to_integer(hex_in));

end architecture;
```

This is not a character enumeration type (all of it's members are identifiers).

Essentially you can association a value with an identifier or character literal. In this case the hex value input to the loop up used to produce your seven segment display value is also used to set the value of a signal of the enumerated type:

[image: enum.png]

You can think of it as extra information unless you use the enumerated type as the index type to your seven segment value look up. (And VHDL allows you to do that).

If as Dave Tweed suggests you wanted to recognize seven segment values in a sparse fashion, you'd map them to your enumerated type:

```
architecture fie of enum is
    type ss_enum is (ss_0, ss_1, ss_2, ss_3, ss_4, ss_5, ss_6, ss_7, ss_8,
                     ss_9, ss_A, ss_B, ss_C, ss_D, ss_E, ss_F, unknown);
    signal sseg: ss_enum;
    signal seven_seg:   unsigned (6 downto 0) := "1000000";
    function sseg_enum (sevenseg: std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)) 
                                  return ss_enum is
    begin
        case sevenseg is
            when "1000010" =>  
                return ss_D;  
            when others =>       -- we're  going to fill this in, right?
                return unknown;
        end case;
    end function;
begin
COUNT:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        if seven_seg < "1000100" then
            seven_seg <= seven_seg + 1;
        else
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

LOOKUP_ENUM:

    sseg <= sseg_enum(std_logic_vector(seven_seg));

end architecture;
```

In this case that sparse look up is done with a function using a case statement (and we can see the example is sparse indeed).

You can see there's an added enumeration value for seven segment values that aren't useful mapped.

That gives us:

[image: enum_fie.png]

This method can also be done in most waveform viewers in some generally non-portable fashion. Because in this case the enumerated type signal wouldn't be used anywhere you'd expect it to get gate eaten in synthesis. (Without any output ports mapped to pins this entire example 'design' would be gate eaten anyway).

Comment: I think you may have missed the point of the question. The way I read it, the OP wants to take an arbitrary 7-bit value on a bus, say, "1000010", and have it displayed as "ss_D" in the simulator. Or in the more general sense, can one assign specific bit patterns to specific enumeration symbols without enumerating all 2^N possibilities?

Comment: "But the question here is, generally how to assign custom value to VHDL enum type?" Don't conflate position and value. You can supply the enumerated types as input to what ever produces your seven segment values "(And VHDL allows you to do that)."

Comment: @user1155120 you are correct in your understanding of the question.